# Python finding first positive solution for equation

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to find the first positive solution for the following equation using Python 3.7.1. Only `N` is a variable and must be positive, the rest are constants.

```
np.sqrt(I1/I2)*np.tan(np.sqrt(N/(E1*I1))*L1)+np.tan(np.sqrt(N/(E2*I2))*L2)=0
```

I have tried the following, but the solution depends on `N_initial_guess` and isn'n necessarily the first positive solution greater than 0.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import matplotlib.pylab as plt  

I1=32297.094187844657
I2=1017.876019762602
E1=220000
E2=220000
L1=137
L2=145
equ2= lambda N : np.sqrt(I1/I2)*np.tan(np.sqrt(N/(E1*I1))*L1)+np.tan(np.sqrt(N/(E2*I2))*L2)

# Plot it

N = np.linspace(0, 100000, 10000)

plt.plot(N, equ2(N))
plt.xlabel("N")
plt.ylabel("equ value")
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_ylim([-10,10])
plt.grid()
plt.show()

N_initial_guess = 30000
N_solution = fsolve(equ2, N_initial_guess)

print("The solution is N", N_solution)
print("at which the value of the expression ", equ2(N_solution))
```

[plot of function delivering second solution with N_initial_guess=30000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Pmsg.png)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the `fsolve` function before, so I cannot tell you how did you get that warning. My suggestion to find the first positive solution is to plot a nice graph. You can simply bound the range of y to `(-10, 10)`, then you can easily see that the first positive solution is between 40000 to 60000. Then, set a better initial guess, say 40000.

```py
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

I1=32297.094187844657
I2=1017.876019762602
E1=220000
E2=220000
L1=137
L2=145
def equ2(N):
    return np.sqrt(I1/I2)*np.tan(np.sqrt(N/(E1*I1))*L1) \
               + np.tan(np.sqrt(N/(E2*I2))*L2)

# Plot it

N = np.linspace(0, 100000, 10000)

plt.plot(N, equ2(N))
plt.xlabel("N")
plt.ylabel("equ value")
plt.ylim(-10, 10)    ######### set this 
plt.grid()
plt.show()

N_initial_guess = 40000     # set a better guess
N_solution = fsolve(equ2, N_initial_guess)

print("The solution is N", N_solution)
print("at which the value of the expression ", equ2(N_solution))
```

Output:

```
The solution is N [44079.92175617]
at which the value of the expression  [-3.99680289e-15]
```

Comment: Thanky you, I edited my original post and also set the y-axis range like you suggested. This works, however I am looking for a stable way to solve this without manualy looking at the plot and setting the `N_initial_guess`.

Comment: Searching for a good initial guess is quite a mathematical problem.

Comment: You mean there is no "clean" analytical way to solve this problem and this is a common struggle? If there is no better way, then I could then just write a loop which increases my `N_initial_guess` until the result matches my criteria, this would at least automate my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if there are any analytical way or programmatic way to find good initial guess. Sorry, I am not an expert in mathematics.